# install4j: exclude uninstaller from control panel

Tags: java, installation, install4j

is it possible to configure install4j so that it doesn't add the uninstall details to control panel? Ideally, a switch passed on the installer commandline would be best.

I'm wrapping an install4j generated installer within an MSI - I want the MSI installer to show in control panel, but not the wrapped install4j installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry in the "Programs and Features" section of the Windows control panel that invokes the uninstaller is created by the "Register Add/Remove item" action. In the default installer template, this action is present under the "Installation" screen. Go to Installer->Screens & Actions to locate that action.

Generally, you can use the "Condition expression" property to prevent an action from running. The easiest way is to set the condition expression of the above action to

```
!Boolean.getBoolean("noUninstaller")
```

and pass the command line argument

```
-DnoUninstaller=true
```

If you think that the -Dname=value syntax of system properties is too ugly, you can also use `context.getExtraCommandLineArguments()` in the condition expression script to detect an argument like `-noUninstaller`.